# Google Cloud task migration (python 3) - how to include target?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

We have an application in Google App engine and are migrating from Python 2.7 to Python 3. One particular client in Python2.7 that we need to migrate is the task_queue. The code in Python2.7 is as follows -

```
    task = taskqueue.add(
            url='/backendtask',
            target='worker',
            method = "POST",
            queue_name = 'backend-task',
            params={
                "task_data"     : task_data
            })
```

In the above syntax, we have set the target to "worker". "worker" is another instance(service) in the same app engine project. The purpose of this is to ensure "worker" can be in a different configuration of the instance from the main application.

The new code in Python 3.7 using Cloud Task syntax looks like this -

```
        task = {
                'app_engine_http_request': {  # Specify the type of request.
                    'http_method'   : tasks_v2.HttpMethod.POST,                            
                    'relative_uri'  : '/backendtask'                        
                }
        }
```

How do we specify the 'target' for this relative_uri? The 'worker' instance is on https://worker-dot-appengine.appspot.com/backendreport

There is no mention of this in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks). We would like to use the AppEngine task not the HTTP target task

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. The field is 'app_engine_routing'. documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/migrating-push-queues).